# How can I represent addition of classes in UML class diagram?

Tags: python, class, oop, uml, relationship

I am required to use a UML  class diagram to represent a model implementation done in Python.
I have a case where
`Kernel_A` + `Kernel_B` → `Kernel_AB`
using `__add__()` method in the class.

These are class variables of a model, called `Model_A`, which is itself also a class variable of a class which performs estimation, lets call this `Algorithm_A`.
`Algorithm_A` also has a class variable which is a separate model, `Model_B`, which is not related to the kernels.

Primarily, I am not clear on how to represent the relation between the kernel classes in the UML class diagram. Meaning that the `kernel_AB` is an addition of the classes `kernel_A` and `kernel_B`. Both of `kernel_A` and `kernel_B` have the same methods, but different class variables given that they are dictated by different parameters.

I am also not entirely clear on how to represent the class variable relationship between `Model_A` and `Algorithm_A`. Is this an aggregation relationship, shown with a diamond arrow?

To reiterate the components and relations:

- `Kernel_A` + `Kernel_B` → `Kernel_AB` (`__add__` method to create `Kernel_AB`)
- `Kernel_AB` → `Model_A` (`Kernel_AB` class variable of `Model_A`)
- `Model_A` → `Algorithm_A` (`Model_A` class variable of `Algorithm_A`)
- `Model_B` → `Algorithm_A` (`Model_B` class variable of `Algorithm_A`

Comment: Welcome! This seems to be an interesting question.  But the wording is ambiguous and raises many questions. Could you show some minimal code to clarify?  Not being a python expert, it's for example not clear to me if you generate a new class, a new class with multiple inheritance, or if you use just compose objects of different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear about the `Kernel...` stuff.  Nevertheless here an answer to your question about the relations between algorithms and models:

[image]

I assumed that `Model_X` were unrelated classes.